# What does 'bridging language barrier' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What exactly does the phrase "Bridging language barrier" means?

I feel that it makes the following sense:

"To overcome the obstacles between languages or in a language".

Does it any sense mean to "Create obstacles in languages"?

Comment: When two or more people speak different languages, there is a barrier, an obstacle, to communication. In particular there is a *language* barrier. In order to overcome this barrier, we can build a bridge over it (though as a metaphor, it makes more sense to break down or break through a barrier, or build a bridge over a gal or chasm instead of a barrier... but non the less). Therefore if we *bridge* the *language barrier*, we've found a way to let people who speak different languages communicate effectively. So you order interpretation is correct, and no your second isn't possible.

Comment: @DanBron I find your comment very useful. Why not post it as a answer?

Comment: I am sure, however, that there are many puns on the phrase which suggest creating or worsening a language barrier.  One might well encounter one such pun and not recognize that a term is changed, reversing the meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks So what can we do to make it more the intended way?

Comment: @Raju Because I'd have to substantiate or corroborate it, somehow, so it would be more than one man's opinion, and that's a lot more effort than I'm inclined to put in right now.

Comment: You don't need to change anything -- I'm just saying that if you encounter a phrase which *seems* to be the same as above but, from its context, appears to be implying something different you should look for subtle wording differences.

Comment: @DanBron - That's my opinion as well.

Comment: @HotLicks That's because it happens to be the correct opinion ;)

Comment: @DanBron -Yeah, you got lucky that time!